# Simple int to string conversion... Int to const char* invalid

Tags: c++, string, int, sstream

Setting: On Qt Creator, I call this function. I have imported all sstream, string, etc. all of it is in the same class and is defined well in the header file:

```
std::string int2str(int x) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    return ss.str();
}
```

and inside a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::string s = int2str(i); // error lies on this line
    // a line of Qt code
}
```

I get the error `"Invalid conversion from int to const char* [-fpermissive]"`. Which is weird, because isn't that exactly what this function is supposed to be doing?

**EDIT:** Didn't know how to use Qt Creator to get more details...Sorry everyone.

Error:

> Initializing argument 1 of '`std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,_Alloc>::basic_string(const_charT*, const_Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]`' [-fpermissive]
>   @ basic_string.tcc line 214 (/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc)

**EDIT2::** 
Dumb mistakes, one of which includes, speaking of namespaces. never specifying where `int2str` was; used `myClass::` in front of it and now it's all good - as everyone thought.

Comment: The error is not in the code you show.

Comment: You are not showing the code that is failing. Because the code you are showing works. So, when asking a question, please include the failing code

Comment: Can you post full error message from 'Console' tab, not 'Problems' tab, including file and line information?

Comment: The only way I could see this error occurring is if `operator<<` for `std::stringstream` is only overloaded to take a `const char *`, but nothing better for an `int`, which would mean a pretty bad implementation. For example, if you have a function `void foo(const char *);` and call it with `foo(5);`, it will give this error as well.

Comment: :/ I figured it'd be so... I showed the only error message I get in, the code related to the line of the error (int2str(i)) the error happens on compile.
Oh I'm silly maybe this next edit could help...

Comment: you should probably just check out the `std::to_string` function, it doesn't exactly that but will be more efficient.

Comment: We're getting closer here. We are still lacking some information to help you since the line of code that causes the problem isn't shown here. Can you post the code for `int2str()`?

Comment: It looks like `int2str` declared returning `int` somewhere. (may be in header)

Comment: @Lol4t0: in addition to the scope specification, that was indeed the problem

Comment: Consider writing it as your answer and giving it the checkmark. This helps other users finding good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False information was given; header function was *not* defined properly since the function returned an `int` instead of a `std::string`.  Additionally namespaces: did not have `myClass::` in front of the function `int2str` in its implementation.